# Keyword Implements not working Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was making a testing app for learning android where I tried to use "implements" to use a class function interface, as I seen in an android tutorial. But I am getting error and can't use the interface functions when I try to follow the syntax used by the tutorial for the interface I developed my self. The syntax used by the person in tutorial was like

```
public class alfred extends Activity implements View.onClickListener()
{some code .....}
```

the same way I did but for my own designed interface like

```
public class tony extends Activity implements Myinterface.foo()
{...}
```

but I cant do Myinterface.foo() but can do Myinterface and then use all the interface functions. Why is this so? 
Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Could you post how your MyInterface is defined?

Comment: Could you give link to that tutorial? I really doubt that it would tell you to use `implements Type.method()` instead of `implements Type`.

Comment: It is a fairly simple interface. A few simple functions,, just for testing purposes.

Comment: It is android tutorial, in which the guy uses implements for View.onClickListener() .

Comment: That it *not* valid syntax. It should be `.. implements SomeInterfaceType`. Fix/address this issue *before* continuing.

Answer (score 3):

In the Class View theres a Interface defined

```
 public interface OnClickListener {
        void onClick(View v);
 }
```

Look closely its View.OnClickListener() not View.onClickListener()

Try

```
public class tony extends Activity implements Myinterface
```

Comment: If OnClickListener is an interface, why is () used with it in this case View.OnClickListener() ??

Comment: Thats a fault in your Tutorial, you need no () for implementing an interface

Comment: No offense but I think you are wrong. It is not an interface because when we using setonclicklistener() function, inside its arguments, goes new View.OnClickListener() so I think its not the fault of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're experiencing is exactly what should be happening! I'd guess and say there is an error in the tutorial you are following.

To use an interface, you implement the interface, not the methods it exposes. So for example, you implement `View.OnClickListener` (*not* `View.OnClickListener.onClick()` - this is where the error is I imagine), or in your case `Myinterface`. You have to then put the required methods in the class (e.g. `onClick(View)`, or `foo()`).